# Flying Text Focus - Blurry to Crisp animation

Tags: text, jquery-animate, focus, blur

I have some text animating left and right from 0 opacity to 1 so that it fades in as it moves. I'd like to add a blur animation to give the impression the text is moving towards us. Not sure how to do this.

```
var $activeText = $(".active-text");

// the following is loop'd

$activeText.animate({opacity:1, left: '5%'}, 4000, 'swing').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);
```

Is it possible to include a blur animation or focus to run at the same time? I've not found a library yet that does this.  The $activeText is Text as well, not an image.

Cheers

---

EDIT

I've tried this:

$activeText.animate({opacity:1, left: '5%', textShadowBlur: 0}, 4000, 'swing').animate({opacity: 0, textShadowBlur: 20}, 1000);

but it's not working, grrr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the best way eventually was to use text-shadow and give it a high spread. When this faded in it gave the effect of a blur.

CSS

```
text-shadow: 0 0 0.3em white;
```

As far as I can tell there is no way to animate text-shadow.